# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am executing the following query :

```
WITH rg(id, childid, NAME) 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                0 ChildID, 
                NAME 
         FROM   kuaf 
         WHERE  id = 1000 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT c.id, 
                c.childid, 
                k.NAME 
         FROM   kuafchildren c 
                JOIN rg p 
                  ON ( c.childid = p.id ) 
                JOIN kuaf k 
                  ON ( c.id = k.id )) 
SELECT DISTINCT ka.id 
FROM   rg, 
       lm_approvals app 
       JOIN kuaf ka 
         ON ( ka.id = app.useridentifier ) 
       JOIN dtree dt 
         ON ( dt.dataid = app.dataid ) 
WHERE  app.dataid = 25773 
       AND app.isapproved = 0 
       AND Replace(ka.NAME, ka.type + '_', dt.ownerid + '_') = rg.NAME
```

But I am ending with the following error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "ChildID" of recursive query "rg".

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you took the time to properly format your SQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the first SELECT or the anchor part of the resursive CTE as follows, it will work

```
SELECT id, 
                CAST(0 as int) ChildID, 
                NAME 
         FROM   kuaf 
         WHERE  id = 1000
```

This is the case we experience generally with empty string or NULL is selected at this step.
So explicitely defining the type at anchor SELECT is required for CTEs

Answer (score 0):

I myself have not tried this
Judging by the documentation
it is necessary to explicitly convert
0 type like kuafchildren.childid
through
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
or
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
expression - 0
data_type [ ( length ) ] ) same as kuafchildren.childid

You can try to write instead 
0 ChildID 
kuaf.id*0 ChildID
This might work if kuaf.id type the same as the kuafchildren.childid

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
;WITH CTE RG AS (
SELECT   Id,
         0 AS 'ChildId',
         Name
FROM     Kuaf
WHERE    id = 1000

UNION ALL

SELECT   C.Id,
         C.ChildId,
         C.Name
FROM     KuafChildren C
         INNER JOIN RG ON (C.ChildId = RG.ChildId)
)
SELECT ...
```

I assume ChildId column datatype is int